# Actionscript 3 sitelocking

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs6

For first time Im trying make sitelocked flash file, and I dont know how to do that.
I found a couple tutorials on the net and none of them worked for me.
I will post one that I found online.

Before that I ll explain my situation a little bit.

I exported all classed on frame 2, on frame one 1 I have preloader graphics and simple
progress event for my preloader.

This is how my Main(class) public function looks before adding sitelocking code:
Please if you can, add 'somelocking code' to this code below.

```
    public function Main()
    {
    loaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, preloaderDone);
    }

    private function preloaderDone(e:Event):void
    {
       showMenu(); // game will start here
    }
```

Everything works ok, but now I would like to check domain name after preloader is done.
Actually Im trying to set loaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, preloaderDone)
only if flash file is hosted on correct domain, else I want to show text field
'Accesdenied'. After I did this, flash file is locked on all domains, I tried with
different domains but it wont work, I also tried to put absolute path to swf file,
like mywebsite.com/myflashfile.swf. It always show acces denied. This is the code that
I found online and I tried to use it.

```
    public function Main()
    {
    var url:String=stage.loaderInfo.url;
    var goodPattern:RegExp=/^(http:\/\/)(www\.)?somewebsite\.com/;

    if (goodPattern.test(url)==true) 
    {
    loaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, preloaderDone);
    } 
    else 
    {
    myTxtFieled.text = "Acces denied."
    stage.addChild(myTxtField);
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, try tracing the result of your `stage.loaderInfo.url`.  You might find that a RegExp is overkill whereas a simple comparative operator could suffice.

For example, running "test.swf" on my local system traces the following path `file:///C|/Sites/myDomain/subdirectory/test.swf`, whereas when placed on a server, it appears as `http://myDomain.com/subdirectory/test.swf`.  Fairly straightforward.

This would simplify your code to...

```
public function Main() {
    if (this.loaderInfo.url == "http://myDomain.com/subdirectory/test.swf") {
        loaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, preloaderDone);
    } else {
        var txt:TextField = new TextField();
        txt.text = "Acces denied.";
        addChild(txt);
    }
}
```

That, of course, would lock your SWF to only call `preloaderDone()` if its run from a specific directory.  If you want to be able to move it around on your server, and only be concerned with the domain, you might do a simple string search instead.

```
if (this.loaderInfo.url.indexOf("myDomain.com") != -1) {
```

Comment: Actually I used this if (this.loaderInfo.url.indexOf("myDomain.com") != -1) ... addeventListener, else show acces denied. Only one line of code?? I didnt know that. Thanks alot man you are great, I cant believe it works :)

Comment: Uh, just to be clear, that if statement is in place of the one I wrote above, but yes: it should do the job, I think.  :)

Comment: i think a string comparsion would be better than indexOf - otherwise the URL "www.myEvilDomain.com/test.swf?cheating=myDomain.com" would pass your test